# как перевести js ajax запрос в c#

Tags: javascript, c#

```
$.ajax({
      crossDomain: true,
      type: "GET",
      url: "url",
      data: {a:"a",b:"b"},
      dataType: "xml",
    });
```

как оформить объект data в c#?

```
WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(url);
wr.Method = "GET";
wr.Headers["dataType"] = "xml";
wr.Headers["data"] = ?;
```

пробовал

```
wr.Headers["data"] = "{a:1234,b:\"b\"}";
```

ответ `Wrong input data`

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что `data: {a:"a",b:"b"}` - это заголовок (`Header`)? Вы ведь можете нажать F12 в браузере, выполнить запрос и во вкладке "сеть" увидеть что и как отправляется. Увидите там небось `url?a=a&b=b`. Вот это вообще беcсмыслено `dataType: "xml"`, ибо `GET` запрос не имеет тела. Ну и также, в C# `WebRequest` **устарел**, не копируйте слепо из интернета код, почитайте документацию, посмотрите альтернативы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WebRequest` устарел еще до того как динозавры вымерли.

Сейчас модно писать нормальный асинхронный код для работы с сетью. А для HTTP запросов использовать `HttpClient`.

Потом, есть [документация](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) `$.ajax()`

> **data**
> Type: `PlainObject` or `String` or `Array`
>
> Data to be sent to the server. If the HTTP method is one that cannot have an > entity body, such as GET, the data is appended to the URL.

Так как у вас запрос GET, то следовательно аргументы надо передавать как параметры урла.

```cs
private static readonly HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    string url = "https://google.com";

    Dictionary<string, string> queryData = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        ["a"] = 1234.ToString(),
        ["b"] = "b"
    };

    UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(url)
    { 
        Query = new FormUrlEncodedContent(queryData).ReadAsStringAsync().Result
    };
    Console.WriteLine(uriBuilder.Uri);

    string response = await _client.GetStringAsync(uriBuilder.Uri);
    //Console.WriteLine(response);
}
```

Да, я знаю, что Uri query строится в C# страшновато, но уж что дал Microsoft, то и используем.

```
https://google.com/?a=1234&b=b
```

А `dataType` - это вам вообще не нужно в C#, смотреть в документацию по ссылке выше.

Comment: dataType это тип возвращаемых данных, xml или json

Comment: @axmed2004 вам сервер вернул что-то не то? Вы проверили код? Вы не указали, что это обязательно и какой тип данных вы ожидаете от сервера. Вообще это регулируется добавлением в запрос заголовка `Accept`, но опять же, вам точно это нужно?

Comment: спасибо. работает. посмотрел в дебаггере итоговый запрос, выглядит как ваш